# Issue with tweening data in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, pixi.js, gsap

First look at this script and run it.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.side-canvas')
let w = element.offsetWidth;
let h = element.offsetHeight;

const config = {
  startPositionX: 50,
  startPositionY: 100,
  ease: Elastic.easeOut,
  count: 4,
  distance: 90,
  radius: 10,
  fall: 100

}

let renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(w, h,
    {antialias: true, transparent: true}
);

element.appendChild(renderer.view);

renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
renderer.view.style.display = "block";
renderer.autoResize = true;
renderer.resize(w, h);

let stage = new PIXI.Container();
stage.interactive = true;

let line = []

let lineData = {
  id: 0,
  x1: 0,
  x2: 0,
  y1: 0,
  y2: 0
}
let drawLine = function () {
  console.log(lineData)
  if (line[lineData.id]) {
    line[lineData.id].clear()
  }
  line[lineData.id] = new PIXI.Graphics();
  line[lineData.id].interactive = true

  line[lineData.id].position.set(config.startPositionX, config.startPositionY);

  line[lineData.id].lineStyle(1, 0xf44336);
  line[lineData.id].moveTo(lineData.x1, lineData.y1);
  line[lineData.id].lineTo(lineData.x2, lineData.y2);

  stage.addChild(line[lineData.id]);

  line[lineData.id].lineData = lineData
}

for (let j = 0; j < config.count - 1; j++) {

  lineData = {
    id: j,
    x1: j * config.distance,
    x2: (j + 1) * config.distance,
    y1: 0,
    y2: 0
  }
  drawLine()

}

let circle = []
let rect = []
for (let i = 0; i < config.count; i++) {

  rect[i] = new PIXI.Graphics();
  rect[i].interactive = true;
  rect[i].lineStyle(1, '#000');
  rect[i].beginFill(0xFF00FF, 0.1);
  rect[i].drawRect(-config.startPositionX, -config.distance / 2, config.distance, config.distance);
  rect[i].endFill();
  rect[i].x = config.startPositionX + i * config.distance;
  rect[i].y = config.startPositionY;
  rect[i]['which'] = i;
  stage.addChild(rect[i]);

  circle[i] = new PIXI.Graphics();
  circle[i].interactive = true;
  circle[i].lineStyle(0);
  circle[i].beginFill('#000000', 1);
  circle[i].drawCircle(0, 0, config.radius);
  circle[i].endFill();
  circle[i].x = config.startPositionX + i * config.distance;
  circle[i].y = config.startPositionY;
  circle[i]['which'] = i;
  stage.addChild(circle[i]);

  rect[i]
    .on('mouseover', onHover)
    .on('mouseout', onLeave);

}

let actionDone = false

function onHover(e) {
  actionDone = false
  

  const backX = this.position.x;
  const backY = 100;

  TweenMax.to(circle[this.which], 0.9, {pixi: {x: backX, y: backY + config.fall}, ease: config.ease})

  if (line[this.which - 1]) {
    lineData = line[this.which - 1].lineData

    TweenMax.to(lineData, 0.9, {
      y2: config.fall,
      onUpdate: drawLine,
      ease: config.ease
    })

  }

  if (line[this.which]) {

  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    actionDone = true
  }, 300)
}

function onLeave(e) {
  //   this.data = e.data;
  const backX = this.position.x;
  const backY = config.startPositionY;

  let tl = new TimelineMax({repeat: 0, repeatDelay: 0, delay: 0, yoyo: false});

  tl.to(circle[this.which], 0.9, {pixi: {x: backX, y: backY}, ease: config.ease}, "+=0")

  if (line[this.which - 1]) {
    lineData = line[this.which - 1].lineData

    let tl2 = new TimelineMax({repeat: 0, repeatDelay: 0, delay: 0, yoyo: false});
    tl2.to(lineData, 0.9, {
      y2: 0,
      onUpdate: drawLine,
      ease: config.ease
    }, "+=0")

  }

}

animate();

function animate() {
  renderer.render(stage);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
 .side-canvas {
        position: relative;
       margin:0 auto;
        width: 364px;
        height: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/PixiPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.6/pixi.min.js"></script>
    <div class="side-canvas"></div>
```

Can anyone offer a refactor for this hover animation, to play correctly?
**Red** lines should come back to start place!
How can I animate two elements?
Is there any way to make better functionality?
Is there a native way to animate canvas elements without an external library?
Thank you, in advance.